# How are defending Pokémon's CP adjusted?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the recent update to Pokémon Go (Android version 0.42.2, iOS version 1.11.2), changes were made to the way training gyms worked. According to the [patch notes](http://pokemongolive.com/en/post/ver-update-101016/):

> Trainers can now bring six Pokémon to battle at friendly Gyms. **The CP of the Pokémon you are battling may be temporarily adjusted lower for your training session.**

How is this determined? I have attackers ranging in CP from the mid-1000s to low-2000s. Will the temporary adjustment only take into account my highest CP Pokémon overall, or will it adjust depending on what I have selected to take into battle with me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this post](https://pokemongo.gamepress.gg/news/real-0412-patch-notes):

> Defending Pokemon CP now scales down based on your trainer level. If a Pokemon is higher level than your trainer, its level will scale down to your trainer level + 2 and its CP will be lowered accordingly for that battle.

Therefore, the scaling down is not dependent on your Pokemon's CP, but rather your ***trainer*** level compared to the defending Pokemon's level.